# CKEditor always alerts when exiting before saving even when submitting changes

Tags: javascript, forms, ckeditor

I'm using the checkdirty function for checking my ckeditor for any changes before exiting.  It's working ok but the alert comes up even when I submit the changes. What code would I change and where to get this submit button to skip the check and just save the changes?

Here's my code.

```
for ( var name in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
    if(submit_it)
        return false;

    if ( CKEDITOR.instances[ name ].checkDirty() ) {
        return evt.returnValue = "You will lose the changes made in the editor.";
    }
}
}

var submit_it = false;

if ( window.addEventListener )
    window.addEventListener( "beforeunload", beforeUnload, false );
else
    window.attachEvent( "onbeforeunload", beforeUnload );
```

Here's my javascript code in the head.

```
var warn_on_leave = false; 

CKEDITOR.on('currentInstance', function() {                
    try { 
        CKEDITOR.currentInstance.on('key', function() {        
            warn_on_leave = true; 
        }); 
    } catch (err) { }                                        
});

$(document.activeElement).submit(function() {   
    warn_on_leave = false; 
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
    if(warn_on_leave) { 
        return 'Attention: Your text has not been saved!'; 
    } 
});
```

Here's my submit button:

```
<input type="image" src="button_update.gif" border="0" alt="Update" name="udpate" title=" Update ">
```

Comment: Your first code has a syntax error, probably a copy-paste issue where one line with a function definition is missing. Can you check the code?

Comment: Also, your variable `submit_it` never gets assigned true. What's the point of the variable?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the similar problem and after Googling for 2 hours, I figured out a solution, what I have done is registered an event before the save command is executed:

```
var saved = false;

CKEDITOR.replace('#myTextArea', options);

CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] = {
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.on( 'beforeCommandExec', function(event)
        {
            if (event.data.name === 'save') {
                saved = true;
            }
        });
    }
};

$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    if (saved === false) {
        if (CKEDITOR.currentInstance.checkDirty() === true) {
            return 'You have some unsaved changes on this page, are you sure you want to leave?';
        }
    }
});
```

Though this is very old question, I think my answer will help some one.